# Are there any problems if I install an old version of a Linux distro?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, distributions, version

I've got a computer with 512 MB of RAM, and a 50 GB hard disk.

**Question:** will I have any problems if I install an old version of Ubuntu, Knoppix, or any other distro? For example: may I have any security problems if I access the Internet?

I already have Puppy Linux installed, and it works great. I'm just looking for any alternatives.

Comment: Have you considered [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net)?

Comment: Thanks George Edison, +1. :) Thanks to MaxMackie too. :P

Comment: If puppy works then stick with it. What CPU does the system have? What video hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you can have security issues and bugs, cos every new version brings, besides new features, fixed bugs and security issues

Comment: altough, that version were used, can got security issues and bugs which were founded after release date.. just M.O

Comment: You're right. I asked a friend meanwhile, and he gave me the same answer. Moreover, he said there is no need to look for an old verison, as I can safely use the latest version of Kubuntu or Lubuntu. So I think I can mark this as the best answer. Grazie. :)

Comment: PS: "can got"? "might have". :)

Comment: ignis: ups! :-P

Comment: This is not a true answer, because security issues and bugs are not just fixed in the current release but also back-ported to previous releases. The LTS (Long Term Service) releases are typically supported for 2 years, so you could install one of those from last year and still get current security patches. In this case if you can use the latest version do, but the concern about security is only relevant if it is a given release is UNSUPPORTED. Some distros as old as ten years old still have current security patches.